# JQuery addClass to menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I make this menu that is stack on top and the section "Representaciones" is shown on the same page but below a welcome image. When I clic it work but if I refresh the page, the class "selected" disappears from "representaciones" and it shows on "home". 
I can't make it work, thanks for your help.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
        <a href="index.php" class="selected">HOME</a>
        </li>
       <li>
       <a href="#representaciones">REPRESENTACIONES</a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <a href="productos.html" target="_parent">PRODUCTOS</a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <a href="eventos.html" target="_parent">EVENTOS</a>
       </li>
       <li>
       <a href="contacto.php" target="_parent">CONTACTO</a>
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
#menu{
padding-left:225px;
margin: 0 auto;
position:absolute;  
width:900px;
height:142px;
background-color:#f6f6f6;
}

#menu ul li a {
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    list-style: none outside none;
    font-weight:200;
    color: #919ca1;
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding-top:60px;
}

#menu ul li a:hover{
    color: #f6f6f6;
    background-color:#d3242c;
    padding: 61px 40px 61px 40px;
}

#menu ul li a.selected{
    color: #f6f6f6;
    background-color:#d3242c;
    padding: 61px 40px 61px 40px;
}
```

jquery that i found in this web

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu li a').click(function () {
        $('#Menu ul li a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: no idea what it is you're asking, but heres a FIDDLE for anyone else who can... http://jsfiddle.net/cgD9Y/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that is how browsers work. If you refresh your page, It will restore to it's initial state.

You would need to store its state in a cookie or local storage, and fetch that state after the page is loaded and reselect the desired element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `ctMenu` to `menu`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu li a').click(function () {
        $('#menu li a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/3jjeX/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu li a').click(function () {
        $('#menu li a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```